# Getting below Exception when upgrade Spring version from

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, mule

I am trying to upgrade spring version from 4.2.2.RELEASE to 4.3.15.RELEASE and getting below error when we are running cucumber test cases. I have excluded all other versions and I have checked using 'mvn dependency:tree' it is not showing any other spring versions.

Console output:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at cucumber.runtime.io.ClasspathResourceLoader.newInstance(ClasspathResourceLoader.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ClasspathResourceLoader.instantiateSubclasses(ClasspathResourceLoader.java:56)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:81)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:61)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
    at com.<some package>.CucumberTestRunner.<init>(CucumberTestRunner.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ClasspathResourceLoader.newInstance(ClasspathResourceLoader.java:74)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ClasspathResourceLoader.newInstance(ClasspathResourceLoader.java:74)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ClasspathResourceLoader.instantiateSubclasses(ClasspathResourceLoader.java:56)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ClasspathResourceLoader.instantiateExactlyOneSubclass(ClasspathResourceLoader.java:42)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadObjectFactory(JavaBackend.java:43)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.<init>(JavaBackend.java:31)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'muleTestInstance' defined in class path resource [..../.../mule-test-embedded.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/NamedBeanHolder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.spring.SpringFactory.<clinit>(SpringFactory.java:42)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/NamedBeanHolder;
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolveSchedulerBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:205)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$2.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:108)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:103)
    at com.<some package>.afterPropertiesSet(MuleTestServer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1689)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    ... 45 more
```

Can you please suggest for solution.

Comment: Where did you change the Spring version? How are you running this? And which version of Mule is used?

Comment: I have changed spring version in pom file. Mule version is 3.7.3,                                                                       I am getting these exception when I am running cucumber test cases and also when I am trying to deploy in tomcat server.